# Move a text div by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a div that contains some text and i want to be able to move that div when i click and hold my left mouse button and when my pointer cursor location is changed the div location is changes too.
my js code:

```
$(() => {
    $(document).on("mousemove", "#div", (e) => {
        const x = e.pageX
        const y = e.pageY
            $("#div").css("top", y - 50)
            $("#div").css("left", x - 100)
            console.log(e.pageY)
            console.log(e.pageX)
    })
})
```

my html code:

```
<div id="div">
        <span>Hello World!</span>
        <span>Look at Me!</span>
        <span>I'm Moving!</span>
    </div>
```

my problem is that i don't know to use which event. i want click and mousemove events together.
what should i do now?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery-UI Draggable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many methods to enable Drag and Drop in your script. For example, please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API You may want to use a Framework like jQuery UI as it can make setting up Drag and Drop a lot easier.

Comment: @Barmar yes i use draggable but it's not working. i don't know why

Comment: It might be more helpful to post your attempt at using it, then we can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example, based on the following [Demo](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <span>Hello World!</span>
  <span>Look at Me!</span>
  <span>I'm Moving!</span>
</div>
```